# How can I execute 2 Order By clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm currently stuck with this problem here. Can I know how can I have 2 ORDER BY clause in my query so that i can order Main_Actor_Payment & Supporting_Actor_Payment by DESC. With the clause I have now I'm only able to order supporting_actor_payment. Can someone please help me to order both of them in descending order. Thank you very much.

[Results of current query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHQkU.png)

```
SELECT main_actor.First_Name,
        main_actor.Last_Name,
        main_actor.Payment_amount AS MAIN_ACTOR_PAYMENT,
        supporting_actors.First_Name,
        supporting_actors.Last_Name,
        supporting_actors.Payment_amount AS SUPPORTING_ACTOR_PAYMENT
FROM main_actor
INNER JOIN supporting_actors USING(MOVIE_ID)
ORDER BY supporting_actors.Payment_amount DESC
```

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (3-5 rows) and desired output for this data. As formatted code and formatted table, not as screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `main_actor.Payment_amount` next to the `supporting_actors.Payment_amount`  in your `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT main_actor.First_Name,
        main_actor.Last_Name,
        main_actor.Payment_amount AS MAIN_ACTOR_PAYMENT,
        supporting_actors.First_Name,
        supporting_actors.Last_Name,
        supporting_actors.Payment_amount AS SUPPORTING_ACTOR_PAYMENT
FROM main_actor
INNER JOIN supporting_actors USING(MOVIE_ID)
ORDER BY supporting_actors.Payment_amount, main_actor.Payment_amount DESC
```

**FROM**

```
ORDER BY supporting_actors.Payment_amount DESC
```

**TO**

```
ORDER BY supporting_actors.Payment_amount, main_actor.Payment_amount DESC
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this before but it doesn't work either

Comment: Can you provide us a sample table data and the table structure?

Comment: Can I have your email address please, so that I can send you the full script it will be easier that way. Thank you.

Comment: @ryan I don't think we are allowed to post our email addresses here

Comment: It’s okay I’ll post mine, naveenjc10@gmail.com. Please inbox me.